# Recommend how to use .spl files from "CAD Star"

Tags: pcb

Hello I am a software engineer with no experience in getting PCBs created. My friend has designed a PCB in CAD Star and we are ready to get it manufactured, however the files are .spl format and I am struggling to find a company that supports .spl files.

How can I output files that PCB makers can use?

Comment: I'd be very much concerned if your friend can do a PCB, but can't generate the correct files for a board house...

Comment: Not sure why Cadstar calls them '.spl' but last time I used it the files for each layer are actually Gerber and the drill files are Excellon drill format.  Any PCB manufacturer should be able to work with them.

Comment: I have edited your question to get rid of the request for a supplier recommendation, which is not allowed here, but the question is still useful I think,

Comment: Simple. Get your frient to export Gerber files. If Spehro's right about .spl actually being Gerber. you will be able to open them in a Gerber file viewer, like gerbv, and check they look about right. Then rename them to avoid further confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to generate Gerber files for that. I've never worked in program of yours, but they all usually have gerber generator. Google "cad star gerber" or something like that to find how to do that. For example, eagle generates .pcb and .sch for board and schematic, but it's not what you send the manufacturer. You need to generate gerber files, they're supported by everyone, although there may be some manufacturer-specific issues and/or rules regarding those. Usually you just send the gerber and if something doesn't fit in your gerber, the manufacturer replies and asks to correct this or that, at least that happened to me.

Answer (score 2):

There is a video [here](https://youtu.be/_QqnIX3SIo0) that describes the arcane batch process for this particular EDA program. Between that and the help file you should be able to do it.

You want separate [RS274-X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerber_format) files for each layer (a double sided board might have 7 files including outline, masks, copper, and silk screen), plus an NC drill file in Excellon format. There are usually a number of options in generating the files such as resolution that are probably hidden in the files referenced by the batch file. Usually the defaults will work well.

There is no standard naming for Gerber files and you can change the batch file names and/or extensions, or rename them manually as long as they are actually in the correct format. Any PCB maker can use a set of files like that.

Typical file extensions are .gbr for the Gerber files and .tap or .txt or .nc for the NC drill files. They're all human-readable ASCII and the RS274-X files start with a block defining the apertures.

But the various EDA programs have tended to use whatever they felt like- Orcad, for example, used different extensions for each layer such as .SST for silk screen top, .BOT for bottom copper etc.

Comment: With Altium, the Gerber files usually have the format [board name].g**, where the extension indicates the layer - .gtl = top copper, .gbl = bottom copper, .gto = top silkscreen, etc.

Comment: @PeterBennett Probably the use of extensions is a carry over from the bad old 8.3 days, and the 8 characters would be used up just to name the PCB project. Orcad and Altium (née Protel) both date back to 1985 (well pre-Windows). I vaguely remember using very buggy OrCAD on a monochrome plasma laptop. Back when we thought usable professional-level autorouting was just around the corner.

Answer (score 0):

CADSTAR produces 'spool' files by default when you run each manufacturing output individually [you can rename them]. It's better to automate the file-set generation using the CADSTAR batch processing where you can define output filenames for each file generated. Whatever method you use, use a gerber viewer to check all the outputs [particularly the drill file outputs]